# ¿Cómo ejecutar tags escritas en un TextArea hacia un <div> en tiempo de ejecución?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Lo que quiero es que al escribir alguna etiqueta en el `TextArea` que el texto escrito en este se dirija hacia un `<div>` y así poder visualizar el código en tiempo real.

Lo que no logro hacer es que se reconozcan las etiquetas.

Cuando coloco las etiquetas `<pre><code> </code></pre>` desde el código ahí si me funciona, pero no al escribirlas en tiempo de ejecución desde el `TextArea`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
});

function getTexto(){
 var texto = document.getElementById("txtArea").value;
 return texto;
}

function escribirCodigo(){
 $('#vistaPrevia').text(getTexto());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
 <textarea id="txtArea" cols="20" rows="10" onkeyup="javascript:escribirCodigo();"></textarea>
</center>

<div id="vistaPrevia" style="padding: 20px;">
 <!-- Aqui se escribe el codigo obtenido del TextArea -->
</div>
```

Comment: Es claro estás añadiendo texto , para añadir `HTML` sería `$('#vistaPrevia').html(getTexto());`

Comment: Muchas gracias, soy algo nuevo en esto de html y javascript, Saludos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Está claro , en su código **`está añadiendo texto empleando el método`** `text` y no `HTML`, su línea sería

```
$('#vistaPrevia').html(getTexto());
```

Pero hay que tener en cuenta que para esto no hay necesidad de emplear *Jquery* , podría  modificar la propiedad [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) para añadir nuevo contenido.

```js
function escribirCodigo(){
 var texto = document.getElementById("txtArea").value;
 document.getElementById('vistaPrevia').innerHTML = texto;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txtArea" cols="20" rows="10" onkeyup="escribirCodigo();"></textarea>
<div id="vistaPrevia" style="padding: 20px;"></div>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, te lo agradezco. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <textarea onkeyup="codigoHTML();" name="" id="texto" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        <div id="resultado"></div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    function codigoHTML() {
        div = document.getElementById("resultado");
        texto = document.getElementById("texto").value;
        div.innerHTML = texto;
    }

</script>

</html>
```

PRUEBA CON ESTE CODIGO

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta!